# Redirect angular js page in browser from Java (Spring) Filter

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I have created an SQL injection filter in my Spring Boot application that intercepts each request and validates input for a possible SQL injection. If input is invalid, then I want to redirect user back to login page. With my code, I can see internal call being made through DevTools but browser is not redirecting to specified page.

Filter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
String url = req.getRequestURL().toString();

Enumeration<String> enumeration = request.getParameterNames();
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
    String paramName = enumeration.nextElement();
    String value = request.getParameter(paramName);
    String sqlRegex =
                    "\\b(ALTER\\s+TABLE{0,1}|CREATE\\s+TABLE{0,1}|DELETE\\s+FROM{0,1}|DROP\\s+TABLE{0,1}|EXEC(UTE){0,1}|INSERT\\s+INTO{0,1}|MERGE\\s+INTO{0,1}|SELECT\\s[0-9a-zA-Z_*]*\\s+FROM{0,1}|UPDATE\\s[0-9a-zA-Z_]*\\s+SET{0,1}|UNION\\n+ALL{0,1})\\b";
    int bufferOverflowLength = 4000;
    if (value != null && (Pattern.compile(sqlRegex).matcher(value.toUpperCase()).find()) || value.length() >= bufferOverflowLength) {
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String redirectUrl = req.getContextPath() + "/logout";
        resp.setStatus(403);
        resp.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
        return;
    }
}
```

}

How can I force browser to redirect to logout page?

Update:
As per @buettner123's comment, I have implemented an httpInterceptor in Angular, but that is still unable to intercept my request from Filter.

Angular Interceptor code

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$location', '$injector', '$q', function ($location, $injector, $q) {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            console.log("Request intercepted");
            return config;
        },
        'responseError': function (rejection) {
            console.log("Response Error Intercepted");
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        },
        'response': function(response) {
            // do something on success
            console.log('I am done');
            var status = response.status;
            console.log(status);
            return response;
          }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: AngularJs is a single page application. Following your approach with the filter, I would answer the request with a respective http code (e.g. 400) and have an error interceptor on the AngularJs part which does the redirect, using the AngularJs routing

Comment: I have added an httpInterceptor in AngularJS which is working fine for other requests but unable to intercept request initiated from my Filter.

Comment: Please try with `resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);` instead of `sendRedirect`

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution here in-case someone else might find themselves with the same problem

Filter.java

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String url = req.getRequestURL().toString();
    System.out.println("url : " + url);

    Enumeration<String> enumeration = request.getParameterNames();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {

        String paramName = enumeration.nextElement();
        String value = request.getParameter(paramName);
        String sqlRegex =
                        "\\b(ALTER\\s+TABLE{0,1}|CREATE\\s+TABLE{0,1}|DELETE\\s+FROM{0,1}|DROP\\s+TABLE{0,1}|EXEC(UTE){0,1}|INSERT\\s+INTO{0,1}|MERGE\\s+INTO{0,1}|SELECT\\s[0-9a-zA-Z_*]*\\s+FROM{0,1}|UPDATE\\s[0-9a-zA-Z_]*\\s+SET{0,1}|UNION\\n+ALL{0,1})\\b";

        if (value != null && (Pattern.compile(sqlRegex).matcher(value.toUpperCase()).find())) {
            HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
            if (session != null)
                session.invalidate();
            HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "SQL injection detected");
            return;
        }
    }
```

}

main.js

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$location', '$injector', '$q', function ($location, $injector, $q) {
return {
    'request': function (config) {
        return config;
    },
    'responseError': function (rejection) {
        if (rejection.status == 403 && rejection.data.includes("SQL injection")) {
            console.log("Forbidden Resource");
            window.location.href="redirect url";
        }

        return $q.reject(rejection);
    },
    'response': function(response) {
        return response;
      }
};}]);
```

Make sure js code is under config element